# Convert Following Python Code to Google Apps Script Code Based on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

Can anyone help me please convert this following Python code to Javascript, because I'm lack of JavaScript coding, sorry for my bad English. Thanks!

```
nameVar = input("Please enter Variation name: ")
nameEach = input("Please enter suffix name: ")
itr = 0
varArray = []

while True:
    each = input("Item no. " + str(itr + 1) + ": ")
    itr += 1
    if (each == "0"):
        break
    elif (each.isnumeric()) and (each.isnumeric() != 0):
        varArray.append(each + " " + nameEach)
    elif (each.isnumeric() == False):
        varArray.append(each)

text = """
[{"name":"%s","visible":true,"variation":true,"options":%s}]
""" % (nameVar, varArray)

output = text.replace("'", '"')

print(output)
```

Comment: will this be executed on backend or browser? the `input` functions vary based on that

Comment: No, I will use this on Google Apps Script based on JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const nameVar = prompt("Please enter Variation name: ");
const nameEach = prompt("Please enter suffix name: ");
var itr = 0;
const varArray = [];

while (true) {
    const each = prompt(`Item no. ${itr + 1}: `);
    itr++;
    if (each == 0) break;
    else if (!isNaN(each) && each != 0) {
        varArray.push(each + " " + nameEach);
    }
    else if (isNaN(each)) {
        varArray.push(each);
    }
}
    
var text = `[{"name": ${nameVar},"visible":true,"variation":true,"options": ${varArray}}]`;

var output = text.replace("'", '"');

console.log(output);
```

Comment: The code is good. I would prefer having semicolons and explicit curly braces even for one-line loops. There is one mistake in line `else if (isNan(each))` - there should NOT be a **colon** there. That's why I prefer having explicit curly braces - make you less confused when switching languages. Also I would prefer `let` over `var`